# SQL Query to identify switching pattern

Tags: sql

I have a sample example data below which showcase user id, start date, end date, product subscribed, quantity, price and subscription id.

```
User_id Start_date             End_date         product    quantity     price   Sub id
100     01AUG16:20:52:36                         abc         1           $10     1
101     07AUG16:17:10:30    20JAN17:01:16:14     abc         1           $10     2
101     20JAN17:01:16:14    20JAN17:01:22:21     xyz         1            $5     3
101     20JAN17:01:22:21                         abc         1           $10     4
102     06AUG16:19:51:28    23DEC16:19:15:28     xyz         1            $5     5
...
```

I would like to create a derived field which tells weather customer has "switched" the product, and also if possible if there is a pattern that shows switching behavior.

Final expected output:

```
User_id Start_date             End_date         product    quantity     price   Sub id   Status
100     01AUG16:20:52:36                         abc         1           $10     1        Active
101     07AUG16:17:10:30    20JAN17:01:16:14     abc         1           $10     2        Terminated by Switch
101     20JAN17:01:16:14    20JAN17:01:22:21     xyz         1            $5     3        Terminated by Switch
101     20JAN17:01:22:21                         abc         1           $10     4        Active by Switch
102     06AUG16:19:51:28    23DEC16:19:15:28     xyz         1            $5     5        Terminated
```

Any insights on how to query/approach would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please define what the statuses mean.

Answer (score 0):

The Query is below but it is very **Fragile**. So, **if you have the option to insert/update the `Status` field while inserting/updating the record would be much reliable**

```
SELECT
    M.*,
    CASE 
    WHEN (LAG(M.User_id) OVER (ORDER BY M.User_id, M.Start_date, M.End_date)) IS NULL 
          AND (LEAD(M.User_id) OVER (ORDER BY M.User_id, M.Start_date, M.End_date)) <> M.User_id 
          AND M.End_date IS NULL 
          AND (LAG(M.End_date) OVER (ORDER BY M.User_id, M.Start_date, M.End_date)) IS NULL 
          THEN 'Active'
    WHEN (LAG(M.User_id) OVER (ORDER BY M.User_id, M.Start_date, M.End_date)) <> M.User_id 
         AND (LEAD(M.User_id) OVER (ORDER BY M.User_id, M.Start_date, M.End_date)) IS NULL 
         AND M.End_date IS NOT NULL 
         AND (LAG(M.End_date) OVER (ORDER BY M.User_id, M.Start_date, M.End_date)) IS NULL 
         THEN 'Terminated'
    WHEN (LAG(M.User_id) OVER (ORDER BY M.User_id, M.Start_date, M.End_date)) = M.User_id 
         AND M.End_date IS NULL 
         AND (LAG(M.End_date) OVER (ORDER BY M.User_id, M.Start_date, M.End_date)) IS NOT NULL 
         THEN 'Active By Switch'
    WHEN (LAG(M.User_id) OVER (ORDER BY M.User_id, M.Start_date, M.End_date)) = M.User_id 
         AND M.End_date IS NOT NULL 
         AND (LAG(M.End_date) OVER (ORDER BY M.User_id, M.Start_date, M.End_date)) IS NOT NULL 
         THEN 'Terminated By Switch'
    WHEN (LAG(M.User_id) OVER (ORDER BY M.User_id, M.Start_date, M.End_date)) <> M.User_id 
         AND    (LEAD(M.User_id) OVER (ORDER BY M.User_id, M.Start_date, M.End_date)) = M.User_id 
         AND M.End_date IS NOT NULL 
         THEN 'Terminated By Switch'
    END AS 'Status'
FROM MyTable M
```

**The Results are:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . it is hard to say exactly what you want, but this should produce the results you want:

```
select t.*,
       ( (case when end_date is null then 'Active'
               else 'Terminated'
          end) ||
         (case when min(product) over (partition by product) <> max(product) over (partition by product)
               then ' by Switch'
               else ''
          end)
       ) as status
from t;
```